# Interpreting g-formula intervention density

Tags: conditional-probability, causality

I am reading the appendix section A.2 from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.patter.2020.100008) on the parametric g-formula and I am struggling to understand the "intervention density" when the intervention depends on the natural value of treatment.

For brief background on notation, assume an observational dataset with treatment $A_k$,  vector of covariates $L_k$, and censoring $C_k$ at times $k = 0,1,2,...K$. Overbars indicate history; e.g., $\bar{a}_2 = (a_0,a_1,a_2)$.

I am struggling to understand the final density ($f^d$) in this passage:

[image]

I don't understand what it means to have a random draw from the density of $a_k$ conditional on the *natural* value of treatment at $k$ (and history).

What precisely is the "natural value" of treatment? And how should we understand an intervention density conditional on this value?